# monitor resource usage on remote pc

Tags: remote, resources

I am looking for a free software tool that periodically (daily) gives me an overview of a PC at a different location.
The overview then contains at least:
- how many times / how many minutes of processor load > 90% (90 is an example value);
- ditto for memory
- notification if the hard disk gets <5% free space etc.
- system crashes, etc.

In addition, it would be nice if this is possible:
- gives notification when new programs are installed / updated
- gives notification when windows updates are installed
- reports a crash or incorrect termination.

I am thinking of a program that can send me an overview every day, or place a file so that I can read it on my request, so that I can keep abreast of the performance of the system.

I am not looking for detailed log file generator which are used for deeply analysis in case of issues, this is more to get an high level overview of general system usage.

Both pcs run Windows 10.
If possible, a free tool / solution.

Who has ideas, tips?

Thanks in advance.
M.

Comment: SU isn't a software recommendations site. You should ask this question over at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: WMI will easily give you all of this information but I sure as heck am not going to write it for you.  Learn WMI and Powershell.. then call the thing from the task scheduler. This app would be simple to make.